# add small bash script to cloudbuild.yaml

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform, yaml, google-cloud-build, cloudbuild.yaml

I have a `cloudbuild.yaml` file for google cloud (GCP). I would like to grab the `version` from `package.json` using a simple bash script `$(node -p -e "require('./package.json').version")` (or any other way). How can I add this to my `cloudbuild.yaml` file?

I tried putting the script in `substitution` but it didn't work.

```
# gcloud submit   --substitutions=_VERSION="1.1.0"

steps:
  # build the container image
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
    args: ["build", "-t", "gcr.io/${_PROJECT_ID}/${_IMAGE}:${_VERSION}", "."]
  # push the container image to Container Registry
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
    args: ["push", "gcr.io/${_PROJECT_ID}/${_IMAGE}:${_VERSION}"]
  # build the container image
  - name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
    entrypoint: gcloud
    args:
      [
        "run",
        "deploy",
        "${_SERVICE_NAME}",
        "--project",
        "${_PROJECT_ID}",
        "--image",
        "gcr.io/${_PROJECT_ID}/${_IMAGE}:${_VERSION}",
        "--platform",
        "managed",
        "--allow-unauthenticated",
        "--region",
        "${_REGION}",
        "--set-env-vars",
        "${_ENV_VARS}",
        "--ingress",
        "internal-and-cloud-load-balancing",
        "--quiet",
      ]
images:
  - gcr.io/${_PROJECT_ID}/${_IMAGE}

substitutions:
  _REGION: us-east1
  _PROJECT_ID: my-dev
  _SERVICE_NAME: my-client
  _IMAGE: my-client
  _VERSION: $(node -p -e "require('./package.json').version")
  _ENV_VARS: "APP_ENV=dev"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Guillaume's answer, you can use a bash script with two `$$` instead of 1 `$`, like so `$$(node -p -e "require('./package.json').version")`. **However**, if the command you're attempting to use isn't available (`node` will not be available), it's best to pull it from a file that you can make in the step above like in Guillaume's answer:

```yaml
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
    entrypoint: bash
    args: 
      - -c
      - docker build -t gcr.io/${_PROJECT_ID}/${_IMAGE}:$$(cat ./package_version) .
```

**UPDATE**: This is our entire script

```
  - name: 'node'
    entrypoint: bash
    args:
      - -c
      - |
        echo "$(node -p -e "require('./package.json').version")-$BRANCH_NAME-$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)" | sed 's/\//-/g' > _VERSION
        echo "Building version $(cat _VERSION)"
```

which prints `<package-name>-<version>-<git_hash>`

Answer (score 3):

It's one of the bad side of Cloud Build. You can't pass variable from one step to another one. Only `/workspace` is kept between steps. And the substitution variables are only static (predefined or set at pipeline runtime).

The solution here isn't so easy.

- You need to add a step to get the version and write it in a file

```
- name: 'node'
  entrypoint: bash
  args:
    - -c
    - node -p -e "require('./package.json').version" > /workspace/node_version
```

- Then use it in your steps, like that

```
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
  entrypoint: bash
  args: 
    - -c
    - |
       VERSION=$${cat /workspace/node_version}
       docker build -t gcr.io/${_PROJECT_ID}/${_IMAGE}:$${VERSION} .
```

The double dollar $$ is to indicate that is a linux command and not a Cloud Build variable

Comment: Sadly `VERSION` is coming up empty. I feel like your answer is right but something isn't working with the `VERSION` value

Comment: Even when I manually made the file to `cat` this method to get the version on my local machine doesn't work: ```bash: ${cat ./package_version}: bad substitution
invalid argument "gcr.io/my-project/my-client:" for "-t, --tag" flag: invalid reference format```

Comment: I couldn't get the variable setting to work, so I used `$$(cat ./package_version)` instead

Comment: I'm not expert in node and I based my command on what you ask. But, if you find the correct solution thanks to my inputs, it's great!!!

Comment: Yes I appreciate your inputs :) However, it wasn't a node specific issue, I couldn't get that `VERSION` definition to work (the second step which doesn't involve node)